# How to Add speech to messages for sdk v4 Bot

Tags: botframework

How can I add capabilities like session.say(.....) which works for voice channel like Cortana for bot built using v4 sdk.

Here [is good doc for v3 bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-send-activity?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

where can I find similar one for v4 bot ?

Comment: find a book, tool, software library, tutorial ?
It is none of the above. I am asking about the documentation link :) Plz read carefully.

Comment: documentation link is an off-site resource, please read carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cortana documentation on the topic for adding speech for V3 or V4 bots:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/adding-speech

Answer (score 3):

The link you included was for **DirectLine** v3, which is the latest version of **DirectLine**.

However, I believe you got the `session.say` command from [this V3 Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-text-to-speech?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). Unfortunately, it doesn't have a V4 equivalent.

However, most of the Message types have a `speak` or `ssml` property ([JS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/messagefactory?view=botbuilder-ts-latest) / [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.messagefactory?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)) you can use to send the text that will be spoken.

It works the same way. Instead of using (from the V3 doc):

**JS v3**

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session)
    .text('This is the text that will be displayed')
    .speak('This is the text that will be spoken.');
session.send(msg).endDialog();
```

**C# v3**

```
Activity msg = activity.CreateReply("This is the text that will be displayed."); 
reply.Speak = "This is the text that will be spoken.";
reply.InputHint = InputHints.AcceptingInput;
await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

You'd use:

**JS v4**

```
var msg = MessageFactory.text({ text: "This is the text that will be displayed", ssml: "This is the text that will be spoken" });
await context.SendActivity(msg);
```

**C# v4**

```
var msg = MessageFactory.Text(text: "This is the text that will be displayed", ssml: "This is the text that will be spoken");
await context.SendActivity(msg);
```

The `await` line might vary, depending on where/how you use it in your bot.

Note that to test speech, there's a few additional steps to set up. You can find references for that here:

- [Using speech in Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53642065/10860086)
- [Using speech in Web Chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat-speech?view=azure-bot-service-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=azure-bot-service-4.0)
- [Using speech in Browser, Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510767/10860086)

And finally, here's [a sample bot that uses Cortana and speech](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/50.diceroller-skill). Specifically, you can see how it uses `MessageFactory.text` [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/d83423c1c3b3b8a21b8178a0fffecc59de60dc31/samples/javascript_nodejs/50.diceroller-skill/lg/index.js#L20).

Comment: Oh yes I copied wrong link. I fond something related on sendActivities()
look like this is an option too if we use speak property. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/turncontext?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#sendactivity

Comment: Correct. You can create the message through MessageFactory or use sendActivities with the `speak` parameter. If you consider your question answered, do you mind marking it so I can close it off of my tracker? Thanks!

Comment: Just did. Thanks

Comment: Did anyone enable speak functionality in v4 and tested in 4.* version of Bot emulator?? if yes, can you tell me how you enabled speak service in Bot framework emulator?

Comment: @PuneetJoshi [DirectLine Speech](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/directline-speech-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)